# Filter records based on last ISO week for this year and also previous years

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a google bigquery table with `orders` with a DATE column and other columns related to the orders. The starting date of the dataset is from 2021-01-01 (yyyy-mm-dd).

My aim is to filter on the DATE column from last year and this year to the previous iso week. For this, I used the ISOWEEK to create a new column:

```
WITH
  last_week_last_year AS (
  SELECT
    DATE,
    EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE) AS isoweek,
  FROM
    `orders`
  WHERE
    EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM DATE) = EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE())-1
  GROUP BY 1, 2
  ORDER BY DATE 
)
SELECT * FROM last_week_last_year
```

This query results as the following table:

[image: last week]

The issue is that when I filter on the original `orders` table by the `DATE` from the `last_week_last_year` table I get all the orders back instead of just the filtered version.

My method to filter is `WHERE DATE IN (SELECT DATE FROM last_week_last_year)` as seen below.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `orders`
WHERE
  DATE IN (SELECT DATE FROM last_week_last_year)
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

A snapshot of resulting table. It contains all of the records from 2021-01-01 until the latest day.

[image: all records]

How can I make sure that on the latter query the table is filtered based on the first query's dates in DATE column?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the screenshot gives the output of only date ‘2022-02-13’ which  is a part of your expected output according to the query given by you. Could you show a sample  set of data  so that we could see the complete output? Also for your question you can perform [joins](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join_types) on date on your first and later query to verify.